# Running forever node tasks from shell script using ansible on ec2 instanses

Tags: node.js, ansible, forever

I'm new to ansible and was trying to configure my multiple ec2 instances using the configuration management tool.

I was able to run it. However, I am stuck at fag end. I have a shell script (to be run by the playbook) that further has task inside it namely:

```
forever start app.js
forever start serverScripts.js
```

The script does run, but the app is not instantiated with forever. When I do forever list it shows

> "No forever processes running"

but node processes does run in the background (shown below).

> root      9725 65.0  6.1 933920 125432 ?       Sl   17:35   0:02
>   /usr/bin/nodejs app.js

Command used in the playbook:

```
- name: Execute the script
  command: sh {{ path }}/developmentProcessScript.sh
```

Kindly guide me to accomplish running of the script in the exact same manner by forever!

Comment: Which user as you running your playbook as? Do you see the forever process when you try running `forever list` as that user?Can you include your playbook and the command you're using to call the playbook?

Comment: Running as root. Yes, when i run it manually on server it does run normally with forever.

Comment: probably this could help: https://immortal.run/post/ansible/

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to see the forever processes with `forever list` when you run as the same user that's started it.  In this case it's root.

```
sudo su - root -c "forever list"
```

If you want forever to run as a different user, set the `become_user` to something else inside your playbook.

```
- name: Execute the script
  command: sh {{ path }}/developmentProcessScript.sh
  become_user: some_other_user
```